# Bash - wget and mv "command not found"

Tags: bash, command-line-interface

I have this basic script in bash:

```
SOFT=apt-fast
FILE=$SOFT.sh
PATH=$SRCF/$FILE
WWW=http://www.mattparnell.com/linux/apt-fast/$FILE
EXEC=/usr/bin/apt-fast
wget -v -U firefox $WWW -O $PATH
mv $PATH $EXEC
```

The rendered code (with the debugging turned on) is as follows:

```
SOFT=apt-fast
+ SOFT=apt-fast
FILE=$SOFT.sh
+ FILE=apt-fast.sh
PATH=$SRCF/$FILE
+ PATH=/home/rgr/src/apt-fast.sh
WWW=http://www.mattparnell.com/linux/apt-fast/$FILE
+ WWW=http://www.mattparnell.com/linux/apt-fast/apt-fast.sh
EXEC=/usr/bin/apt-fast
+ EXEC=/usr/bin/apt-fast
wget -v -U firefox $WWW -O $PATH
+ wget -v -U firefox http://www.mattparnell.com/linux/apt-fast/apt-fast.sh -O /home/rgr/src/apt-fast.sh
cleanstart.sh: line 132: **wget: command not found**
mv $PATH $EXEC
+ mv /home/rgr/src/apt-fast.sh /usr/bin/apt-fast
cleanstart.sh: line 133: **mv: command not found**
exit
+ exit
```

I have tried almost everything... What foolish mistake am I making here? The script is beeing called like this:

`sudo bash -vx script.sh` #-v for verbose and -x for turning debug mode on

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

This one is easy :> its because you override the "PATH" variable. that is of course the one the system needs in order to find the location of "wget" iteself.

:>

Comment: Same thing just happened to me. A colleague had prototyped a bash script and used 'PATH' as a variable to store an argument. Hilarity ensued.

Answer (score 4):

You've deleted your path with

```
PATH=$SRCF/$FILE
```

leaving only that one something/something value in there.

The path environment variable tells the shell where it should look for executables, and you've toasted it.

Use a different variable name to handle your urls for wget.

Comment: I don't think OP intended to use `PATH` as the special variable used to locate binaries. Look at how it's used in the script.

Comment: Pierre: doesn't tmatter. PATH is a standard environment variable in unix shells, holding the system path.

Comment: This is the correct answer. PATH shouldn't be used as a variable.

Answer (score 2):

One of the variables in your script is called `PATH`. `PATH` is also the name of the special variable used to find executables.

Using another variable name should fix your problem.